# Any free SDK to store and return data?

Tags: android, service, sdk, cloud, storage

I am looking for very simple data storage and retrieval from cloud. A solution something like the Evernote API.

I dont want to use Amazon or Google App Engine as I want to use easy to use SDKs to retrieve data rather than writing my own web Services.

Any suggestions please? This is for using in my Android app.

Comment: Emm, you need an SDK to connect *to* Amazon S3 or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from Evernote, I am able to find Dropbox also has API to store simple data and what I am looking for. I totally wonder why no one tried answering me in spite of having Android tag. Not sure if something is wrong the way I asked.